# How to use where < current_date sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

On our PostgresSQL Database we would like to run a query.

```
Select (*)
Where
domain.blabla.date > 'yesterday'
AND
domain.blabla.date < 'current_date'
```

The goal is to get only yesterday's data.

The error we get is the following:

> [Err] ERROR:  date/time value "current" is no longer supported

Do you see a way to solve it?

Thank you very much!

Luca

Answer (score 1):

For `The goal is to get only yesterday's data`:

```
Select (*) 
from domain.blabla 
Where date_trunc('day', date) = date_trunc('day', current_date - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This query will fetch ONLY yesterday's value**

```
select * from table_name where day > current_date- interval '1 day'
```

OR using `yesterday`

```
select * from table_name where day > current_date 'yesterday'
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7d185)**

Refer to [PostgreSQL Date/Time Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) for more on this

P.S - You don't have to put the function in single quotes `' '`

Comment: `> current_date 'yesterday'` gave me syntax errors (even in the linked sqlfiddle) but `> date 'yesterday'` just worked.

Answer (score -1):

For the current date in SQL you can use

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

For yesterday date in SQL you can use

```
SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
```